# Python - blocks: try, except

Tags: python, try-catch, except

If there are more than one `except:` branches after the `try:`, can we say that:

- one or more of the `try:` blocks will be executed
- none of the `try:` blocks will be executed
- not more than one `try:` block will be executed
- exactly one of the `try:` blocks will be executed

In my opinion, the right answer will be "not more than one `try:`", but maybe "one or more of the `try:`"?

Comment: Where you've written "`try:` blocks", did you mean "`except:` blocks"? You can only have one `try:` block per statement, whereas it can have zero (if there's a `finally:` block), one or many `except:` blocks.

Comment: Exactly one `try` block will be executed, and zero or one `except` block, and zero or one `else` block if present, and exactly one `finally` block if present.

Comment: Thanks a lot, all clear ;)

Answer (score 0):

It will show an error like this:

```
SyntaxError: default 'except:' must be last
```

You can either run this code:

```
try:
   something...
except:
   something...
finally:
   something...
```